# call a javascript pop up from html

Tags: javascript

I want to call a javascript pop up onsame page by clicking hyperlink , called pop up should be a form not any alert message.

Below is the code for hyperlink on which I want to call javascript:

```
<a href="#" id="mylink" 
onclick="display(document.getElementById(${legList.ledgerId}).value); 
return false">${legList.ledgerName}</a>
```

The above code is working fine but printing as a alert message.I am unable to get pop up as a form.Please help me with the code javascript which gets called on clicking hyper link and that pop up should be a form including some text fields for example reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Your question doesn't actually contain a question. Apart from describing your project, please describe your problem as well, where you're stuck, what is happening (as opposed to desired outcome). Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again for an overview of think we like to see in a question, helping us to answer it better.

Comment: What is `display`?

Comment: Hello Trincot, display is a funtion which I was trying to call onclick event but that display function is opening as a alert and when I tried to do some modification in display function, it stopped working.My requirement is I want to open a pop up where I want to store legList.ledgerId and legList.ledgerName in text field in a pop up as readonly like- 102:MyClickedLedgerName. Golez,hope I am cleared with my question now. Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is down to your browser blocking popups. For example, the following works for me in Firefox developer edition:

```html
<a target="popup" onclick="window.open('', 'popup', 'width=500,height=200,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,status=no,resizeable=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,top=500,left=500')" href="http://www.your-site.com">Link</a>
```

Comment: No , this one is working fine but I don't know how to add text fields inside script.

Comment: @ Lukas this is not opening as pop up but it is opening in new window